# How to I upload table to Apache Superset?

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I'm trying to upload a dataset to be viewed in Superset.
I created a postgres databased and able to connect via the URI: `postgresql://user:password@localhost:port`
I created a table called `NYC Taxi` with a table called nyctaxi.

However, when I tried to add the table to superset, I get the following error:

```
Table [nyctaxi] could not be found, please double check your database connection, schema, and table name, error: nyctaxi
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the data in CSV you can load it using the UPLOAD CSV from the source menu.

I have an small demo [here](https://docs.preset.io/docs/small-demos)

Comment: Uploading the CSV results in errors. What I'm trying to do is import the table from my postgresql database.

Comment: To be clear what you want to do is "connect" a table to superset, you already have the table and data in the database. If the error is when ADD TABLE, the table may not be in the schema that you think is. First, test the connection to ensure that works, and in the database screen also select "Expose in SQL Lab" and go to SQL lab and navigate the schemas and tables until you find the table nyctaxi. When you are sure about the table location, you should be able to ADD it or you can even go from the SQL lab do a query such as "select * from schema.nyctaxi", click "explore" and this create a table